# npm update check failed on login

Tags: fedora, chown, software-updates, npm

I have just logged into my Fedora 25 server to see the following message:

```
npm update check failed
Try running with sudo or get access
to the local update config store via
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /root/.config
```

I have not changed any server configuration files since last login, when this message did not appear. In fact, all I did the last time I was remoted on was generate and install an SSL certificate for my website. What could be causing this and how can it be avoided in future?

I am logged in as root.

Running `chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /root/.config` does nothing to fix  the problem. And running:

```
[root@li1531-138 ~]# npm update
```

Manually results in the same error.